# Convert matrix rows into variables

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pattern-matching, formatting, variable-definitions

Can anyone show me how to set all matrix rows to variables. 
For example,
I have matrix `w={{1,2,3},{3,2,1},{0,0,0}}` and I need to set each matrix row to be separate variable that contains the row number of matrix `w` in its name.

For example,
`t1={1,2,3} t2={3,2,1} t3={{0,0,0}`. 
Simply it could be done by writing `t1=w[[1]]` ..., but i have 40 matrices with 200 rows so i need someone to help me do this more efficiently.
Variables represents weights in constrained optimization.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been using _Mathematica_ for a long time, and in my experience what you are asking for indicates a need to re-think your programming strategy. In every situation I can think of, the rows of a matrix of any size can be accessed without assigning each row to a named variable.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I need these rows as variables because i will use them as a vectors in separate optimization problems,and 3 other expressions which analytics should be provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you. Given a symbol, say `t`, and a matrix, say `m`, it will define a set of indexed variables `t[1]`, `t[2]`, ..., `t[n]`, bound to the respective rows of `m`.

```
SetAttributes[assign, HoldFirst];
assign[name_Symbol, matrix_List] := (
  Clear @ name; 
  Do[t[i] = matrix[[i]], {i, 1, Length@matrix}]
  )
```

Generate some data.

```
SeedRandom[42];
m = RandomInteger[99, {5, 4}];
```

> ```
> {
>   {54, 66, 4, 15}, 
>   {6, 3, 95, 32}, 
>   {48, 3, 81, 87}, 
>   {22, 88, 98, 48}, 
>   {44, 36, 71, 46}
> }
> ```

Test

```
assign[t, m]
DownValues[t]
```

> ```
> {
>   HoldPattern[t[1]] :> {54, 66, 4, 15}, 
>   HoldPattern[t[2]] :> {6, 3, 95, 32}, 
>   HoldPattern[t[3]] :> {48, 3, 81, 87}, 
>   HoldPattern[t[4]] :> {22, 88, 98, 48}, 
>   HoldPattern[t[5]] :> {44, 36, 71, 46}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The code as below can achieve the result that you need.

```
Clear@t;
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {20, 4}];
Evaluate[t /@ Range[Length@mat]] = mat
```

Because of (=)[Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) has the attribute [HoldFirst](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html?q=HoldFirst), I use the function [Evaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html?q=Evaluate) to evaluate first before proceeding with `Set`.